# Blender Texture Problem

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm creating a blender project about Mario. I did some colours on it with the material bar below:[image: The material bar]

I did a lot of it, making a Goomba and Mario, my older version is like this:

[image: Original Version]
and then this happened:

[image: Later Version]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: "And THEN this happened". What did you do to get this? Specify, please.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: see discussion in comments, certainly more accurate that my own answer.

I think you just turned into render mode in the viewport : to come back to the other preview mode click on the third button on the list right above options, top right part of the scene. This will give you a basic lighting to help you modelling.

Note however that when you will render, you will render basically what you see in render mode : to get a better result you might want to add multiple softer lights, add an environment etc… to avoid these crazy shadows.

Comment: Sorry, yes he turned to _Rendered_ mode in the viewport, but these black artifacts look like there is something wrong with the geometry... that's not a problem of a lack of soft lights or environment. Or maybe a problem with the graphics card driver.

Comment: Uhm it's true that the artifacts are weird. If the author confirms that the does not fix its issue I'll delete my answer.

Comment: By geometry problem, you mean like flipped normals and/or points at the same place that should be merged? In any case, the OP should share its file.

Comment: That's what I would usually suggest, too. But often people have just certain parts or objects flipped or doubled, whereas in this case it seems to be everywhere. So either the complete scene is doubled or what I suspect to be more likely is a hardware/driver issue.

Comment: I would agree with either unsupported GPU or outdated or bad GPU drivers. The clue for me is in the shadows on the flat plane - there really should be no "bad" geometry, given it's just a plane, so in rendered mode the shadow from the point light should have an evenly interpolated falloff, but it doesn't. - It's constant, but uneven (not the way it would be if it was from colorramp set to "constant" for toon shading, for example).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett out of curiosity do you know why this does not apply in preview mode? A different mechanism is used (e.g. opengl…)?

Comment: The only difference I can really think of is that Material Preview uses a HDRI image for its lighting, and there are no additional light sources, meaning all lighting is _indirect/environment_ lighting. It seems that whatever error is occurring (OpenGL or otherwise), it seems to be limited to direct light  sources in this instance. This is only a guess based off what I can see, of course.